# replace input (file) with newly created file

Tags: javascript, jquery

My guess is there should be an easy fix for my problem. but my lack of knowledge of JS prevents me to solve this.

I have an `input` field for a file, which, after a file is chosen a bootstrap modal popup appears to crop that image with the help of Croppie.js. The image is then shown as it would appear (the cropped version).

My HTML (relevant parts):

```
  <!-- this is where the image will appear -->
  <img src="" class="js-image img-responsive img-thumbnail" id="item-img-output" />

  <input type="file" id="program_header_image_headerImage_file" name="program_header_image[headerImage][file]" class="js-item-upload form-control-file">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 15px">Save</button>
```

JS (relevant parts)

```
$('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function(ev) {
      $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'base64',
        format: 'jpeg',
        size: {
          width: 1920,
          height: 400
        }
      }).then(function(resp) {
        $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
        $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
      });
```

To see it in action here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/jr0y5h7e/17/).

Now when I click the submit button, the original image is uploaded and not the newly cropped one. This makes sense because this is what is in the input. However, how can I make it so that my cropped image is uploaded instead?

Comment: From the HTML result of the page after you crop, `resp` is a Base64 encoded string. As such you could include it in a hidden field in your form to be included in the submission. You could then turn that back in to a binary image on the server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I did what you suggested. But still run into one problem: sometimes the Base64 string is so long, there is a processing problem where the browsers will load forever. Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Comment: I have to say, I am not entirely sure where the problem occurs. I think it is because the string is too long, but can't be certain. The log won't tell me anything because the browser is just loading forever.

Comment: You're probably hitting the size limit of a GET request in the browser. Try using POST if you aren't already

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm already using POST. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not seeing your hidden input field in the fiddle. Or the js that sets its value. You'll need to set the value with something like $imgel.attr('src', e.target.result) then submit it with something like  $('#base64lg').val(result);
                    $('#uploadLg').submit();